# Rotary Knob with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swiftui, slider

So I'm attempting to replicate the normal SwiftUI slider functionality with a rotary knob. I've got the UI coded up and functioning currently connected to a standard SwiftUI slider in order to rotate it.

Now I need to add the rest of the slider functionality(ie $value, range, stride) and the touch functionality(ie knob rotating when dragging up and down, left and right). And Honestly I'm at a lost on the best way to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Below is the main file and the project can be found here on [Github Slider Project](https://github.com/brentbrinkley/CustomSlider/blob/main/Slider/FKKnob.swift)

```swift
//
//  FKKnob.swift
//
//  Created by Brent Brinkley on 3/7/21.
//

import SwiftUI

struct FKKnob: View {
    // Set the color for outer ring and inner dash
    let color: Color
    
    // Minimum appearance value:
    let circleMin: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    // Maximum appearance value
    let circleMax: CGFloat = 0.9
    
    // Because our circle is missing a chunk of degrees we have to account
    // for this adjustment
    let circOffsetAmnt: CGFloat = 1 / 0.09
    
    // Offset needed to align knob properly
    let knobOffset: Angle = .degrees(110)
    
    // calculate the our circle's mid point
    var cirMidPoint: CGFloat {
        0.4 * circOffsetAmnt
    }
    
    // User modfiable control value
    @State var value: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                
                // MARK: - Knob with dashline
                
                Knob(color: color)
                    .rotationEffect(
                        // Currently controlled by slider
                        .degrees(max(0, Double(360 * value )))
                    )
                    .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                                .onChanged({ value  in
                                    
                                    // Need help here setting amount based on x and y touch drag
                                    
                                }))
                
                // MARK: - Greyed Out Ring
                
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: circleMin, to: circleMax)
                    .stroke(Color.gray ,style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 6, lineCap: .round, dash: [0.5,8], dashPhase: 20))
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                
                // MARK: - Colored ring inidicating change
                
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: circleMin, to: value)
                    .stroke(color ,style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 6, lineCap: .round, dash: [0.5,8], dashPhase: 20))
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                
            }
            .rotationEffect(knobOffset)
            
            Text("\(value * circOffsetAmnt, specifier: "%.0f")")
            
            Slider(value: $value, in: circleMin...circleMax)
                .frame(width: 300)
                .accentColor(.orange)
        }
    }
}

struct DashedCircle_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FKKnob(color: Color.orange)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version that I use in one of my projects.

When the drag starts, it sets an initial value (stored in `startDragValue`). This is because you always want the modification of the value to be based on what the knob value was when you started.

Then, I've made the decision to only change values based on the y axis. The rational is this: one *could* change based on absolute distance from x1, y1 to x2, y2, but you run into problems with trying to get negative values. For instance, it would probably make sense that the upper right quadrant would be an overall increase -- but what about the upper left quadrant -- would it lead to positive change (because of the y axis change) or negative (because of the x axis)?

If you decide to go the route of x,y change, this method will still get you set up.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var value : Double = 0.0
    @State private var startDragValue : Double = -1.0
    var body: some View {
        Text("Knob \(value)")
            .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
            .onEnded({ _ in
                startDragValue = -1.0
            })
            .onChanged { dragValue in
                let diff =  dragValue.startLocation.y - dragValue.location.y
                if startDragValue == -1 {
                    startDragValue = value
                }
                let newValue = startDragValue + Double(diff)
                value = newValue < 0 ? 0 : newValue > 100 ? 100 : newValue
            })
    }
}
```

My slider bases the values on 100pt up or down from the control, but you can obviously change those to your preferences as well.

In terms of range, I'd suggest always having the knob go from 0.0 to 1.0 and then interpolating the values afterwards.

Comment: Thank you this was definitely helpful in moving this forward. I'm playing around with it now.

Comment: Question for you @jnpdx. I've got this working but when you tap a knob again it automatically resets to it's initial starting position. How can we avoid that?

Comment: @BrentBrinkley I just copied and pasted the code that I wrote and that is not occurring for me. Are you sure it's my code that is doing this and not a function of a modification you've made or situation you've put it in?

Comment: Found the issue @jnpdx it was an edit I made.

Answer (score 0):

I found the SwiftUI `RotationGesture()` to work perfectly for this in that it allows the intuitive rotation of a knob without the downsides listed in the answer above.

The only unique downside is that it *maybe* users have gotten used to single-finger knob operation, (especially on iPhones) and single-finger drag gesture may be the way to go if you have small knobs in your app that it's tough to get two fingers on.

Having said that, you could always attach multiple gestures and get both. Anyway, thanks to [@jnpdx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560942/jnpdx) for the bit about future gestures starting from where you left off with startRotation, and without further ado:

```swift
import SwiftUI


struct KnobView: View {
    @State private var rotation: Double = 0.0
    @State private var startRotation: Double = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        Knob()
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotation))
            .gesture(
                RotationGesture()
                    .onChanged({ angle in
                        if startRotation == 0 {
                            startRotation = rotation
                        }
                        rotation = startRotation + angle.degrees
                    })
                    .onEnded({ _ in
                        startRotation = 0
                    })
            )
    }
}

// convience Knob to checkout this Stack Overflow answer
// that can be later replaced with your own
struct Knob: View {
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}

struct KnobView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        KnobView()
    }
}
```